# iOS: writing a CGImageRef disk in png or jpeg

Tags: ios, uikit

What is the best way to save CGImageRef to a png or jpeg file in iOS?

For a general cocoa application (not using UIkit), see: [Saving CGImageRef to a png file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1320988/saving-cgimageref-to-a-png-file) but this seems too long and clunky.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using UIKit, the code becomes a simple 3-liner:

```
UIImage *uiImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];
NSData *jpgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(uiImage, 0.9f);
[jpgData writeToFile:path atomically:NO];
```

Comment: @trojanfoe on StackOverflow it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own question, it is explicitly encouraged. see: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: I stand corrected.  What have I been missing all these years?

Comment: However won't the image be upside down? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632702/flip-the-image-when-saving-out-to-disk

Comment: As an aside, in general, I'd suggest PNG format rather than JPG. You get transparencies and lossless compression.

Comment: @Rob thanks. I am aware of that, and needed JPEG specifically.